# zend db quote without quote so more like escape

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$url = 'test/';
$url = rtrim($url, "'");
$url = $db->quote($url);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = '{$url}' OR url = '{$url}/'";
```

But this return: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = ''test/'' OR url = ''test/'/'

I basically want the equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string for Zend.`

Comment: You want like SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = 'test' OR url = 'test/'..??

Comment: yes because the url saved in the database may have either. its wrong I know but quick fix for now

Comment: Quote your query rather than url. Check this zend function [quoteinto](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `like` like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url LIKE '%{$url}/%'";
```

Or even you can try like

```
$url = 'test/';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url LIKE '%{$url}%'";
```